# How to assign a string variable to a SelectCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, connection-string, sqldatasource

I have my two select statements (`Str1`,`Str2`) in two string variables. I also have a condition where the appropriate select statement is selected and assigned to another string (`res`).

This is the select statement that is to be assigned to the `SelectCommand` property of a  `SqlDataSource` control on my web page.

The code is:

```
int id =1;
string Str1 = "Select * from table";
string Str2 = "Select * from table where id = "+id;
string res;
if(id == 0)
{
  res=Str2;
}else
{
  res=Str1;
}
```

My markup looks like:

```
<asp:gridview.....></aspgridview>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server"
  ConnectionStrings="<%ConnectionStrings.ConnStr%>"
  SelectCommand="<%# res%>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How do I assign my string variable `res` to my `SqlDataSource` `SelectCommand` attribute from my codebehind or inline C# code?

Comment: use codebehind if you have conditions like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cann set the SelectCommand property from your code-behind, by adding the following statement after the if/else block:

```
ds1.SelectCommand = res;
```

Then you can remove the expression from the markup code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server"
  ConnectionStrings="<%ConnectionStrings.ConnStr%>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using it like in [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx) aricle on msnd.

If you just append strings like that you're going to have an SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

To programatically assign your `SelectCommand` for your `SqlDataSource`:

```
ds1.SelectCommand = res;
```

Where `res` is your command text.